# Keep content center screen but have it change on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an idea I want to try to implement but I don't know the best way to go about it.

I want to center content on the screen and instead of have it scroll off the screen and new content scroll in, I would like to keep it center screen it fade transform into the next content.

So when the user scrolls to "Content 1" it locks that center screen and then when the user scrolls it fades into "Content 2" and then when the user is scrolling past "Content 3" it goes back to normal scrolling behavior.

How can I do this with vanilla JS and CSS? I need this to work on mobile (touch) and desktop (wheel).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" integrity="sha512-wnea99uKIC3TJF7v4eKk4Y+lMz2Mklv18+r4na2Gn1abDRPPOeef95xTzdwGD9e6zXJBteMIhZ1+68QC5byJZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<p>Normal scrolling content</p>

<div class="min-h-screen flex justify-center content-center items-center">
<h2>Content 1</h2>
</div>

<div class="min-h-screen flex justify-center content-center items-center">
<h2>Content 2</h2>
</div>

<div class="min-h-screen flex justify-center content-center items-center">
<h2>Content 3</h2>
</div>

<p>Rest of the normal scrolling content</p>
```

Comment: Do you mean a scroll effect like this [demo](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) ?  Full instructions on [GIT](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos) and works with mobile.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can try something like `scroll-snap-align` is css to achieve it.
Here is a link that can help you understand `scroll-snap-align`. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-snap-align/

Comment: No, I'm familiar with scroll-snap-align - it's definitely not what I'm looking for.